# Uncaught Syntax Error while creating multiple cookies in javascript using JSON

Tags: javascript, cookies

This is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Example Multiple Cookie</title>
</head>
<body>



Name: <input type="text" id="name">
    Email: <input type="text" id="email">
    Company Name: <input type="text" id="companyName">

    <input type="button" value="Set Cookie" onclick="setCookie()">
    <input type="button" value="Get Cookie" onclick="getCookie()">

<script type="text/javascript">
function setCookie(){
    var object1 = [];
    object1.name = document.getElementById('name').value;
    object1.email = document.getElementById('email').value;
    object1.companyName = document.getElementById('companyName').value;

    var jsonString = JSON.stringify(object1);
    document.cookie = jsonString;
}

function getCookie(){
    if(document.cookie.length != 0){
        var object2 = JSON.parse(document.cookie);
        alert("Name= "+object2.name+"\nEmail= "+object2.email+"\nCompany Name= "+object2.companyName);
    }else{
        alert("Cookie is not set yet");
    }
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

This is the console log:

> VM347:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'N', "Name=abc; "... is
> not valid JSON 
> at JSON.parse ()
> at getCookie (8.3_multiple_cookie_using_object.php:30:36)
> at HTMLInputElement.onclick (8.3_multiple_cookie_using_object.php:14:64)
>  getCookie @
> 8.3_multiple_cookie_using_object.php:30
>  onclick @   8.3_multiple_cookie_using_object.php:14

**Note: I have passed abc,abc@gmail.com and abc into name,email and companyName input fields respectively.**

Comment: document.cookie is never JSON. A cookie can be, but dicument.cookie never is as it is all cookies, name and value

Comment: This has nothing whatsoever to do with PHP. Edited your post for you. Next time please only tag stuff which is actually relevant to the issue, not just a list of all the tech your application is using somewhere. See also [ask] and [What are tags, and how should I use them?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) - thanks.

Comment: Tip: log `document.cookie` to your console at the start of your getCookie function, and see what it _actually_ contains

Comment: @ADyson Ok, I'll take care the next time

Comment: Name=abc; Email=abc@gmail.com; companyName=abc; []

Comment: Your object should be defined as `{}`, not `[]`. It's throwing off the encoding.

Comment: Also, if that's what `console.log(document.cookie);` shows in your `getCookie`, it is most definitely not json, and does not match what `setCookie` is supposed to create.

Comment: @aynber Thanks, the problem has been solved